# Representation as sum of irrational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

> Let $S=\{ x\in(0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q} \,:\, \lfloor 100x \rfloor\in \{ 0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99\}\} $. Find the smallest $k$ such that any $X\in(0,1)$ can be written as $X=x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_k$ where $x_t\in S$ for $1\le t\le k$ and no two of the $x_i$ are equal.

So if we take $X=0.10\overline{9}$ then we must have $k\ge 12$. But i'm having difficulty showing that $k=12$ suffices. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what is supposed to be in $S$.  If it is all of $(0,1)$ except some rationals I can write any $X$ with two numbers.  For your example $X=0.11$ I can write $0.11=(0.01+\frac 1{100} \sqrt 2)+(0.1-\frac 1{100}\sqrt 2)$  Why did you write it as $0.10\overline 9$ instead of $0.11?$

Comment: @RossMillikan: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer that is not larger than $x$. Thus the definition given is equivalent to $S=T\setminus\mathbb Q$ where $T=[0,0.01)\cup[0.11,0.12)\cup[0.22,0.23)\cup\ldots\cup[0.99,1)$. In particular, $0.01+\frac{1}{100}\sqrt{2}=0.0241\ldots\notin S$. Another way to describe $S$ would be, it is the set of irrational numbers in $(0,1)$ such that the first two digits are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $k=12$ suffices, let $y=\frac {0.11}{12}$ and let $z$ be an irrational that is less than $\frac 1{1000}$.  Then $y-6z,y-5z,y-4z,y-3z,y-2z,y-z,y+z,y+2z,y+3z,y+4z,y+5z,y+6z$ add to $0.11$

Comment: Ah! Quite silly of me. Thanks for the post!